# A Drupal site migrated to a new server is slow after going live

Tags: performance, drupal, drupal-7

We migrated a Drupal 7 site to a new server and during the testing, everything was great. We tested everything on the new server before going live and everything seemed to work, and it was at least 5x faster than it was on the old server.

However, once we went live, everything slowed down. We are now getting inconsistent results. On some browsers it seems to load as slow as it used to on the old server. On some browsers it isn't working at all.

I can't give a lot of details about how the migration was done, since that was taken care of by somebody else. What I'm concerned about is why we should get such erratic behavior now that the site is live. It worked fine on the exact same server that it is on right now. There is no reason that I know of for this sort of behavior.

Why did it work so well when pointing to it with a temporary URL, but is working erratically now that we are pointing to it with the real URL?